# How to Scroll to the top on page change in React Location?

Tags: react-location

How to make `ScrollToTop` component like in React Router? I would like to move page view to the top on page change.

Here's an example:

### index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop"
import "./index.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <div>Hello world!</div>,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ScrollToTop/>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

### ScrollToTop.js

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    // "document.documentElement.scrollTo" is the magic for React Router Dom v6
    document.documentElement.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "instant", // Optional if you want to skip the scrolling animation
    });
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

How to create the same with the use of React Location (Tanstack Router)?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the same behaviour by using `useLocation()` hook in the TanStack library, but the props will be different - instead of `pathname` it is called `current`.

Here's the code for **ScrollToTop.js**:

```js
import {useEffect } from "react";
import {useLocation} from "@tanstack/react-location";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
    const {current} = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: "instant", // Optional if you want to skip the scrolling animation
        });
    }, [current]);

    return null;
}
```